# What happens if a coordinator node goes down during a write in Apache Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

Pretty much the title, but I realize that there are a lot of different edge cases here, but I am somehow not able to find a credible source on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If co-ordinator goes down mid request , cassandra drivers are designed to handle such case with retry policy which you can configure.

[More Details](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. But what happens to the data that is already written on some of the nodes? Will it be overwritten again if there is a new coordinator node?

Comment: If same insert query is executed then new entry gets created with latest timestamp